# Java recursive method which adds up digits of an argument

Tags: java, recursion, methods, addition

So I have to write recursive method that adds up value of digits within a certain number. For example, digitSum (1234) returns 10 (which is the sum 1+2+3+4).

So far I have this:

```
public static int digitSum (int n) {
    if(n<10) { return n ;} //basecase      else return !!! ;
￼}
```

What should I add in the !!! part, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write it in plain english: when you have `1234`, initial step should be to do `sum(123) + 4`

When you convert it to code:

```
public static int digitSum (int n) {
    if(n<10) { 
      return n 
    } 
    else 
     return n%10 + digitSum(n/10);
￼}
```

`n%10` gives you the last digit, `n/10` gets you the remaining part.

When you have `n=1234`, `n%10 = 4` and `n/10 = 123`. So according to your plain english `sum(123) + 4` it should be `digitSum(n/10) + (n%10)`

Answer (score 1):

Homework?

1234 remainder 10 is 4, 1234 / 10 is 123 you schould return digitSum(123) + 4